# Runtime error when using vector iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, runtime-error

I'm having a problem with the following code:

```
for(int j = 0; j < ensembleTemp.size(); j++)
        {
            ensemble[ensembleTemp[j]].clear();
            ensemble[ensembleTemp[j]].insert(ensemble[j].begin(),
                                     ensembleTemp.begin(), ensembleTemp.end());
        }
```

ensembleTemp is a `vector<int>`
and ensemble is a `vector<vector<int>>`. I have the following,

> error: vector insert iterator outside range.

What's my mistake?

Comment: Editing, as this doesn't seem to be a compiler error.

Comment: The hint iterator to the insert function must be an iterator to the same vector. you are passing `ensemble[j].begin()` which is only the valid iterator when `j == ensembleTemp[j]`

Comment: @PlasmaHH What hint iterator? This is a vector.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - that probably should have been an answer

Comment: @littleadv: Not totally sure here since I would expect a difference error like "error: attempt to insert into container with an iterator from a different container." (thats what gcc would say. since I have no idea what compiler the OP uses, I can also not tell if that expectation makes sense)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong index for the first parameter of insert, it (presumably) should be

```
for(int j = 0; j < ensembleTemp.size(); j++)
{
    ensemble[ensembleTemp[j]].clear();
    ensemble[ensembleTemp[j]].insert(
        ensemble[ensembleTemp[j]].begin(), 
        ensembleTemp.begin(), 
        ensembleTemp.end());
}
```

The first parameter to insert should be an iterator for the vector being inserted into.

In addition ensemble.size() must be greater than ensembleTemp[j] for all j.

Comment: Shouldn't the first parameter to insert() be `ensemble[ensembleTemp[j]].begin()`?

Comment: @jrok Oops, my proofreading this morning is clearly insufficient :) Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure ensemble.size() is greater than 'j'? and greater than ensembleTemp[j]?

Comment: Do you mean "Are you sure `ensemble.size()` is at least as large as `ensembleTemp.size()`?"